TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation')
I have the spfx extension which renders the items into commandBar from the term store, however when I try to access the page the extension is not loading and throwing the below error tmessage. When I reload the page then the navigation appears.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation')
.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { IGlobalNavProps } from "./IGlobalNavProps";
import { IGobalNavState } from "./IGlobalNavState";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/taxonomy";
import { dateAdd, PnPClientStorage } from "@pnp/common";
const myKey: string = "navigationElements";
import { ContextualMenuItemType, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react';
import { createTheme, ITheme } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Styling';
import { CommandBar, ICommandBarStyleProps } from "@fluentui/react/lib/CommandBar";
import styles from "../NavigationEnApplicationCustomizer.module.scss";
import HelloWorld from './Breadcrumb';
import ModernHeaders  from './ModernHeaderSwitch';


export default class GlobalNav extends React.Component<IGlobalNavProps, IGobalNavState> {

private store = new PnPClientStorage();
    constructor(props: IGlobalNavProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
            loading: false,
            terms: []
        };
    }


    public componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({}, async () => {
            // this portion is responsible for getting terms from term store
            const cachedTermInfo = await this.store.local.getOrPut(myKey, () => {
                return sp.termStore.groups.getById(this.props.termGroupId).sets.getById(this.props.termSetId).getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree({ retrieveProperties: true });
            }, dateAdd(new Date(), "minute", 10));
            if (cachedTermInfo.length > 0) {
                console.log(cachedTermInfo);
                this.setState({ terms: cachedTermInfo });
            }
        });
    }

    public componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('Unmounting the header component.');
    }

    private menuItems(menuItem: any, itemType: ContextualMenuItemType) {
        return ({
            
            key: menuItem.id,
            name: menuItem.defaultLabel,
            itemType: itemType,
            href: menuItem.children.length == 0 ?
                ((menuItem.localProperties != undefined && menuItem.localProperties[0].properties !== undefined && menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.length > 0) ?
                    menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.filter(x => x.key == "_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl")[0].value !== undefined ? menuItem.localProperties[0].properties.filter(x => x.key == "_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl")[0].value : null
                    : null)
                : null,
            subMenuProps: menuItem.children.length > 0 ?
                { items: menuItem.children.map((i) => { return (this.menuItems(i, ContextualMenuItemType.Normal)); }) }
                : null,
            isSubMenu: itemType != ContextualMenuItemType.Header,
            buttonStyles: buttonStyle
        });
    }
    
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IGlobalNavProps> {
        
        var commandBarItems: any[] = [];
        if (this.state.terms.length > 0) {
            commandBarItems = this.state.terms.map((i) => {
                return (this.menuItems(i, ContextualMenuItemType.Header));
            });
        }
        return (
            <>
                {
                    
                    this.state.terms.length > 0 &&
                    
                    <><div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.app}`}>
                        <div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.top}`}>

                            <CommandBar
                                className={styles.commandBar}
                                {...CommandBarProps}
                                items={commandBarItems} />
                            <ModernHeaders />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.appbread}`}>
                      <div className={`ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-fontColor-white ${styles.topbread}`}>
                        <HelloWorld
                            context={this.props.context} />

                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </>
                
                }
            </>
        );
    }
}

Package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.22.3",
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-application-base": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "^1.12.1",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.7.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "csstype": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9": "0.4.47",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.14.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2",
    "spfx-fast-serve-helpers": "^1.18.11"
  }


Whenever something works on second load that points to a timing problem. Term store operations take a very long time generally and this is likely the source of your problem. You are trying to access a property of an object that is (temporarily) undefined somewhere. You'll need to debug it to find out where. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-modern-pages

@DerekGusoff before I deploy to the app catalog, i ran gulp serve and the components rendered without any issues. Would that be because I am importing multiple components ?  and 
